# NetworkStream Read() too slow, takes ~9 minutes for 7.5 MB

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

I've some code, to send file data using TcpClient, but it's too slow.

1. Send sample data of 10 bytes, the data is sent and receive as expected.
2. Send file with just a few MB takes long time

   ```
   public static void SendBytes(TcpClient clientSocket, byte[] outStream)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("SendBytes() number of bytes: " + outStream.Length.ToString());

       byte[] encoded_outStream = EncoderDecoder.Encoder(outStream);

       NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

       byte[] rv = new byte[encoded_outStream.Length + ProgramState.end_networkdata_bytes.Length];

       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encoded_outStream, 0, rv, 0, encoded_outStream.Length);
       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(ProgramState.end_networkdata_bytes, 0, rv, encoded_outStream.Length, ProgramState.end_networkdata_bytes.Length);

       serverStream.Write(rv, 0, rv.Length);
       serverStream.Flush();
   }

   private static int MAX_SIZE = 500000000;
   public static byte[] ReceiveBytes(TcpClient clientSocket)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("G") + "] - " + "ReceiveBytes() started.");
       clientSocket.NoDelay = true;
       NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

       byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[MAX_SIZE];
       clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = MAX_SIZE;

       networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

       int index = GetFirstOccurance(ProgramState.end_networkdata_bytes[0], bytesFrom);
       Debug.WriteLine("ReceiveBytes(), SubArray index: " + index.ToString());

       byte[] tmp_res = bytesFrom.SubArray(0, index);
       byte[] res = EncoderDecoder.Decoder(tmp_res);

       Debug.WriteLine("ReceiveBytes() number of bytes: " + res.Length.ToString());
       return res;
   }
   ```

EDIT: The code for receiving data in multiple chunks

```
    private static int MAX_SIZE = 10000;
    public static byte[] ReceiveBytes(TcpClient clientSocket)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("G") + "] - " + "ReceiveBytes() started.");
        clientSocket.NoDelay = true;

        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = MAX_SIZE;

        byte[] tmp_bytesFrom = new byte[MAX_SIZE];


        while(GetFirstOccurance(ProgramState.end_networkdata_bytes[0], tmp_bytesFrom) < 0)
        {
            networkStream.Read(tmp_bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("G") + "] - " + "ReceiveBytes(), received number of raw bytes: " + tmp_bytesFrom.Length.ToString());
        return tmp_bytesFrom;
    }
```

On sending file with few MB (7.5 MB), the ReceiveBytes() function take: ~9 minutes.
Note: 
1. The Encoder() and Decoder() function does not affect my speed.
2. Reduce the buffer size does not make receiving faster. (tested).

Comment: I would suggest to use a more streaming approach instead of using these large arrays. That would significantly reduce the memory load. Your receiving end now uses a 500MB fixed-size buffer, so you cannot receive 500MB+ data and even for 10 bytes, you allocate 500MB. I have never used `NetworkStream` with such large arrays, but with 64KB chunks sending 7.5MB should be done very fast (assuming a fast network connection). What happens if you send/receive in multiple chunks of max. 64KB?

Comment: I've tested to reduce the size of array to 1000, 10000, and try receiving on multiple chunks. The speed is the same.

Comment: It not the code you posted.  I would start by using from cmd.exe PING (use ping/?) and send large messages and see what the response time are to determine if the connection is good.

Comment: @jdweng I've just added the code for receiving data in multiple chunks, the time for receiving is the same. About the connection, I'm testing on localhost (same machine), so network shoud not be a problem.

Comment: Profile your code to see where the time is spent...

Comment: Don't say it not the connection.  You could be sending your data around the world and that is why it is taking so long. Don't assume your routing is keeping the data local on the machine.  You can use a sniffer to help determine if the delay is on the client or server.

Comment: Could you please try (1) remove `clientSocket.NoDelay = true;` (2) remove `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = MAX_SIZE;` (3) show your `GetFirstOccurance` method and `end_networkdata_bytes` array.